# Laravel : using where inside (with Model)

Tags: php, laravel, where-clause, has-many

I have this Controller :

```php
public function user_predects()
{
    $matches=Match::with('Predect')->get();
    return ($matches);
}
```

and it is get json data like this :

```php
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "m_date": "2021-02-06 22:00:00",
        "home": "Turkey",
        "away": "Italy",
        "h_goals": 0,
        "a_goals": 0,
        "predect": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "user_id": 10,
            "match_id": 1,
            "h_predect": 1,
            "a_predect": 1,
            "player_id": 1,
            "point": 0,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "user_id": 9,
            "match_id": 1,
            "h_predect": 2,
            "a_predect": 1,
            "player_id": 1,
            "point": 0,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
```

Now I want to view same json data but just for one user ,I used this but don't works :

```php
public function user_predects($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username',$username)->get()
    $matches=Match::with('Predect')->where('Predect.user_id',$user[0]->id)->get();

    return ($matches);
}
```

How can I view matches model with predect model for one user?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
public function user_predects($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username',$username)->first()
    $matches = Match::with(['Predect' => function($query) use ($user) {
        return $query->where('Predect.user_id', $user->id);
    }])->get();

    return ($matches);
}
```

You can also read about constraining Eager Loading from the official documentation: [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)